# Interactive menu (autocomplete) in bash with dialog(1)

Tags: bash, autocomplete, dialog

So we can use `dialog --menu ...` to make a menu. And we can quick select the option by first letter of the tag. I want `dialog` to register keystrokes and perform the autocomplete. E.g. we have 3 options:

- Apply migrations
- Create new branch
- Exterminate

If I fill the textbox (a field which is supposed to be filled to perform the autocomplete) something like `ter`, then menu options shrink just to one option

- Exterminate

So then I can just hit `tab` and select this option (or navigate using arrows if there are more options)

How? :)

Answer (score 1):

[`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html#documentation) accepts the first character of labels (when in lists such as checkboxes) as a shortcut, and will cycle through matches if the character corresponds to multiple rows.

The feature is mentioned in documentation for the program and its library as *abbreviation*, e.g., ([library](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog_lib.html)):

> **dlg_button_to_char**
>
> Find  the first uppercase character in the label, which we may use
>   for an abbreviation.  If the label is empty,  return  -1.   If  no
>   uppercase  character  is  found,  return  0.  Otherwise return the
>   uppercase character.
>
> Normally **dlg_draw_buttons** and  **dlg_char_to_button**  use  the  first
>   uppercase  character.   However,  they  keep  track  of all of the
>   labels and if the first has already been used  in  another  label,
>   they  will continue looking for another uppercase character.  This
>   function does not have enough information to make that check.

It does not do autocompletion (doing that would require an additional window).